# How to change "error" key value in ResponseStatusException

Tags: spring-boot, error-handling

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gzvl6.png)
Using ResponseStatusException class from Spring. I want to change "error":"Bad Request" to "error":"custom error"
I do not want to change a message, I can do that from constructor.

Any ideas? Or should I use different class?

Please see

I can not fine a method in ResponseStatusException to change "error." I found how to change "message" only

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, when using ResponseStatusException, status should use the HttpStatus provided by Spring.

If you want to customize response, wouldn't it be better to create a DTO that contains the status and message of the error and return the DTO in the Body of Response Entity?